# how to add user login function into eclipse by plug-in development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to set passwords for eclipse. In other words, only authorized user can access to the platform. I want to add custom login function for eclipse. When I click the shortcut of eclipse, there will come out a popup window needing me to input the username and password. After that, the eclipse platform can be visited. How to implement by eclipse plug-in development?

Comment: You can only really do this in an Eclipse RCP when you would do it on the Splash screen. You can't do this in a plugin added to an existing Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. There comes a new problem that if I make it in an Eclipse RCP, how can the RCP  inherit Eclipse in functionality. That is to say, I want to reserve the Eclipse functionality. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: An Eclipse RCP can include all the normal Eclipse functionality. You just include the Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Is there any example on that the RCP inherits the Eclipse in functionality? Please help me out of this. I've tried but failed.